# Prism v4, MEF WPF DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism, mef

First, a few questions regarding databinding:

- Is the default DataContext for a control set to the codebehind? For example, if I have a variable `orderNumber` in test.xaml.cs, can I just reference it like so in the xaml `{Binding orderNumber}`?
- Is it correct that I can only databind to properties of an object?

I have a Prism service in a separate module/assembly that I import into my Shell application via MEF. I'm trying to databind on it but it doesn't appear to be working.

My workaround is below.
**In my Shell.xaml.cs:**

```
[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
private IRibbonService _menuService;
public IRibbonService MenuService
{
    get
    {
        return _menuService;
    }
}


public void OnImportsSatisfied()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Imports satisfied", "Prism");
    this._moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs>(moduleManager_LoadModuleCompleted);

    //TODO figure out how to properly bind to the ribbon
    Ribbon.DataContext = _menuService;
    RibbonAppMenu.DataContext = _menuService.ApplicationMenuData;
}
```

Is there a way to set the datacontext in xaml prior to an object being set - specifically in regards to MEF / Prism scenario? On my ribbon object I tried `DataContext="{Binding MenuService}"` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the default DataContext for a control set to the codebehind? For example, if I have a variable orderNumber in test.xaml.cs, can I just reference it like so in the xaml {Binding orderNumber}?

No.  By default, there is no DataContext, and its inherited from a parent using the hierarchy mechanisms in WPF.  You need to explicitly set the DataContext for a control, if you want it to have one.

> Is it correct that I can only databind to properties of an object?

Yes.  You can only bind to properties.  If you want two way binding to work, the object must also be a `DependencyObject` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

> Is there a way to set the datacontext in xaml prior to an object being set - specifically in regards to MEF / Prism scenario? On my ribbon object I tried DataContext="{Binding MenuService}" but that didn't work.

This will attempt to set the `DataContext` to the `MenuService` property of the containing DataContext using the hierarchy (ie: the parent control/window's DataContext's MenuService property).  You can't bind into yourself to set the DataContext.

You can create a new object in XAML for use as the DataContext, or have a containing object provide the DataContext for you.

Comment: @Chris: Is MenuService defined in Ribbon or the RibbonWindow?

Comment: The IRibbonService interface and RibbonService class are declared / instantiated in a separate project called Infrastructure, and exported with MEF... then imported into the RibbonWindow with the code used in the question above.

Comment: I tried doing something like this http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/10/wpf-tips-8-use-your-code-behind-for.html where the root xaml element has a DataContext of self but that did not databind, perhaps because I need a DependencyProperty (not sure, I need to read up on what thats used for)